# MongoDB pinging failed for distributed lock pinger caused by WriteConcernFailed:waiting for replication timed out. Error details: { wtimeout: true }

Tags: mongodb

W SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: WriteConcernFailed: waiting for replication timed out. Error details: { wtimeout: true }

In my MongoDB logs i found these kind of error at particular time (18:21 -18:39)on all primaries and secondaries in my replica set and config servers  what causes this kind of issues & will it effect to the cluster and whats the solution to resolve this kind of issue

Answer (score 1):

Your SECONDARY nodes are lagging on replication and your write concern dictates that write to the database should be acknowledged with X nodes, but before the system got enough acks, there was write timeout.

Check `rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()` on all replica sets during time when you have hight load.

Comment: Will this effect to the cluster is it risky

Comment: Only, if you lost your primary (so primary status is moved to other node in replica set) during time when all your secondaries are lagging with replication same time/moment. In that moment you could lost some insert/update if your write concern is one (1). But generally answer to question is no. Your cluster is fine.